# WebView not loading with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to build a `ViewPager` which contains a bunch of `WebViews`.  I'm able to get the `ViewPager` working, however, only the initial `WebView` is loading it's content.  When I swipe to the other views, they are coming up blank.  No error message or anything.  When I breakpoint the code, the `loadUrl` is being hit with the correct Url, so not sure what is going on:

**Activity**

```
public class BrowserPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private  List <String> urls;
    private static int NUMBER_OF_PAGES;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        setContentView(R.layout.browser_pager);

        urls = GetUrls();
        NUMBER_OF_PAGES = urls.getCount();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {            
            return Browser.newInstance(urls.get(index));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {  
             return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;  
        }
   }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class Browser extends SherlockFragment {

    private String mUrl;
    private WebView mWebView;

    public static Browser newInstance(String url) {

        Browser b = new Browser();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);
        b.setArguments(bundle);

        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getArguments() != null)
            mUrl = getArguments().getString("url");     

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    { 
        super.onResume();

        DisplaySite();
    }   

    private void DisplaySite() {

        mWebView = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

        final ProgressBar progess = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
              public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progess.setProgress(0);
              }

              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }

        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

              public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                  progess.setProgress(progress);
              }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably the following line:

```
mWebView = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Here you're asking the `Activity` (!) to find the first view with id `R.id.webview`. Now think what happens when there are multiple instances of the same `Browser` fragment attached to the `Activity`... Exactly, always the first occurrence with that id is returned. In other words: the url will always be loaded into the `WebView` of the first attached `Browser` fragment.

Rather than inflating the `WebView` from the `Activity`, you'll want to inflate the `WebView` relevant to each `Browser` fragment by finding the view in the fragment's root view:

```
mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Basically you need to use the correct scope for the view lookup.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished if you set your adapter to inherit from PagerAdapter. https://goo.gl/0J1aCh

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Page page = pages.get(position);
        Magazine magazine = dispatcher.getMagazine();

        WebView webView = new WebView( activity );
        ActionBar.LayoutParams params =
                new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );

        webView.setLayoutParams(params);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl( magazine.getFileLocation() + "/" + page.getName());

        container.addView( webView );

        return webView;
    }
```